# how to deploy the CLR functions in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2008, deployment, clr, sqlclr

I created a SQL Server Project in VS2008 called 'RegularExpression'.In that Project i created a 'Regex.cs' class and i wrote one function regarding Regular Expression.

Then i Build the solution.

Now My problem is to deploy this solution in SQL server 2008 through scripts.( not just clicking on Deploy in VS2008 ).

I succeeded up to deploy the assmebly of that project in SQL 2008 using `CREATE ASSEMBLY <AName> FROM '<path of .dll>'`

but iam not getting that function i wrote in VS2008 in SQL 2008 Function section.

Comment: Assemblies can be stored as byte arrays within the database. which requires no further deployment effort. I believe this is the default, though others can probably provide more detail.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY [RegularExpression]
AUTHORIZATION [dbo]
FROM < DLL Path > 
WITH PERMISSION_SET = SAFE
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[Regex]    Script Date: 01/23/2010 15:08:01 ******/
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Regex](@Pattern [nvarchar](2000), @Input [nvarchar](2000))
RETURNS [bit] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [RegularExpression].[UserDefinedFunctions].[Regex]
GO
```

http://www.setfocus.com/technicalarticles/clrfunctionforsqlserver_2.aspx

The above links helped a lot

Comment: Re: link 'This domain has recently been listed in the marketplace at Domainnamsales.com Click here to inquire'. I wanted to upvote for the link as well :(