# Add extension to SQL Server Management Studio, which I wrote in C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssms, add-in

I have an extension for SSMS which I write in C# (functions for converting strings in SQL), and I know that it works. How I can add it to SSMS, to in "functions" appeared these functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the MSDN documentation:

[How to: Create and Run a SQL Server User-Defined Function by using Common Language Run-time Integration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2kae45k(v=vs.100).aspx)

[How to: Deploy SQL Server CLR Integration Database Project Items to a SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dahcx0ww(v=vs.100).aspx)

This SO post may also help you: [how to deploy the CLR functions in SQL server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2122754/5395709)